# Connecting four LEDs to a 12 V, 7 Ah battery

Tags: led, batteries, current

[image]

I want to power four LEDs using a 12 V, 7 Ah SLA battery.

I connected four LEDs in series and connected them to the battery, and the light glows.

Can I use this for a long time or does it need some additional components? Will the big capacity battery harm the LEDs?

Comment: Can we have a link to the LEDs, or a photo of the LEDs wiring to the SLA battery?

Comment: it is taken from 220v ac bulb Philips 10w f6500

Comment: You need at least a series resistor to prohibit thermal runaway

Comment: it is taken from 220v ac bulb Philips 10w f6500. i have nt permanently connected just checked with 12v sla battery by using only 4 leds to match arround 12v .tried 5 leds in series,glowing but brightness is low.6 leds are not turning on.updated image

Comment: how much value can I use

Comment: We don't know what LEDs those are and at what voltage/current they originally were powered with, so your question is unanswerable.

Comment: https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/239/Lite_On04202022_LTST_S04TWET_20220310_rev3_0-2940884.pdf . i think it's this

Comment: Your photo shows an LED assembly containing a large number of LEDs, not an individual LED.  How that assembly reacts when connected to the battery will depend on how the individual LEDs in that assembly are wired.

Comment: You might need a CCS (Constant Current Source) for your, possibly sort of 1W 350mA LEDs. The following has some CCS references. How can Rpi Python PWM GPIO pins control and dim LED strips of 1W 350mA? Asked 1 year, 4 months ago Modified 1 year, 4 months ago Viewed 744 times
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/122187/how-can-rpi-python-pwm-gpio-pins-control-and-dim-led-strips-of-1w-350ma

Answer (score 2):

Philips make their own LEDs.
LEDs all have different forward voltages so they **must** have a current limiting circuit. Didn't you notice that the datasheet you posted and all other LED datasheets show **a wide range of forward voltages** from 2.6V to 3.2V? Then four 2.6V need no more than 10.4V (12V will explode them) and four 3.2V need 12.8V (they barely light with 12V).

Comment: Such LEDs typically have a fairly "soft knee" so forward voltage is highly dependent on current as well as temperature and color. One reference from Rohm shows an LED that passes 1 mA at 1.8V and a still "safe" current of 20 mA at 2.2V. https://www.rohm.com/electronics-basics/leds/led-circuit-configuration The 2.6 to 3.2V variation is also +/- 10%. However, I/V has a positive temperature coefficient, so thermal runaway can happen.